# How to use Amazon S3 on Spree-2-2-stable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3, spree

I need to configure my images on Amazon S3, but when I tried to do so under version **2-2-stable** from **Spree**, I realized that this configuration were moved away from the admin panel.

I read somewhere that this configuration was creating some problems, and thus it was removed on 2-2. But I assume that the functionality is still working somehow.

When I try to add these configs to my **config/initialize/spree.rb**, I´m getting an error because these preferences are no longer existing.

```
preference :s3_access_key, :string
preference :s3_bucket, :string
preference :s3_secret, :string
```

These preferences are found on 2-1-stable but not on 2-2-stable

https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-1-stable/core/app/models/spree/app_configuration.rb
https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-2-stable/core/app/models/spree/app_configuration.rb

Is there any way how to get it working in order to use it together with Heroku?

Answer (score 6):

Here is Spree's commit with the changes and some instruction as to how to make configuration changes.
https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/b1d6c5e4b9801d888cc76c05116b814945122207

My understanding is that you can still use paperclip to manage uploading to S3, which I have successfully done using their instructions. I have however had problems getting the save path on S3 to configure correctly. This might get you started ... in an environment config file put the following:

```
  # Paperclip configs
    config.paperclip_defaults = {
      :storage => :s3,
      :bucket => ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'],
      :s3_credentials => {
          :access_key_id => ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
          :secret_access_key => ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
      }
  }
```

I use environment variables for the S3 credentials, so yours will most likely be different. This chunk of code has made uploading files to S3 work, like I said I just can't force a specific file path on upload. Hope that helps.

EDIT - ADDITIONAL INFO:

I added the following to the spree.rb initializer to define a custom upload path and a custom url path.

```
# S3 upload path and url path configuration
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:path] = 'products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
Spree::Image.attachment_definitions[:attachment][:url] = 'products/:id/:style/:basename.:extension'
```

To change default upload sizes you can override the Spree image decorator model. So under app/models add a spree directory and add a file named image_decorator.rb. You can then control the sizes with the following:

```
Spree::Image.class_eval do
  attachment_definitions[:attachment][:styles] = {
    :mini => '48x48>', # thumbs under image
    :small => '350x700>', # images on category view
    :product => '1024x768>', # full product image
    :large => '600x600>' # light box image
  }
end
```

Check out this page for specifics --> http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html

So to sum up, you can do all your general image/S3 configuration by updating your environment initializer, your Spree initializer and overriding the spree image_decorator model.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I will give it a try in the future, but for the moment I decided to go with the 2-1-stable and things are working out properly there.